# Compass plugin Susy not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm running a Rails 4 app and trying to get compass and susy running. I'm getting the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
```

My gemfile group:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'susy'
  ...
end
```

The only CSS line I have (_base.sass)

```
@import susy
```

I've run Bundle Install, and my app is using:

```
Using compass-rails (1.0.3) 
Using susy (1.0.7)
```

Completely lost. I don't have a config.rb file for compass, but from what I gather it isn't necessary after like Rails 3.1/3.2. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `require "susy"` anywhere in your application?

Comment: Shouldn't be needed with a rails application, but I did try under `config/compass.rb`. No change

Comment: See https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/21.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy that issue does not appear to be rails related and is 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You can found the solution in the `compass-rails` [gem documentation](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails#installing-compass-extensions):

You have to add the gem `compass-susy-plugin` instead of `susy`, like this:

```
# Gemfile
…
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'compass-susy-plugin'
…
```

If you are using Rails 4 do not use `group :asset`, it has been [removed](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile), simply add the previous lines to the Gemfile.

Then run:

```
$ bundle
$ bundle exec compass install susy
```

These previous lines will generate files that require `susy` for you.

And finally add this to your `application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.compass.require "susy"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  After `> bundle exec compass install susy` I get `No such framework: "susy"`